# Opencv c++ stereoBM disparity map limited in distance

Tags: c++, opencv, stereo-3d

As I wrote in the title I have a problem with disparity generated from stereoBM.

The problem is that I can see disparities only in a range of distance, i.e. I can see me if I stand from 1 meter to 2 meters, before and after I see only black (holes, using the OpenCV's dictionary).

I need that I can create a depthmap with a distance greater than 2 meters and I don't know why there is this limitation.

Is there any problem related to the calibration or the rectify process?

I hope you can help me.

edit:

https://mega.nz/#!c5BnlCxT!U0EVi2cizy3fJbyfUF7m3haBibhz-SJpecdw0hYjFv8

https://mega.nz/#!RgBnhY4Z!v2CJKVRAPGK0cco1C02AFc8HeUgTCfhrTtWZs4aREqQ

https://mega.nz/#!IpJnRQSb!YVfd094W2KfRr6gdyiduiwJtkr2n13TVaGf1THvTM3A

here there are the raw images(undistorted), the dmap after the rectify process and the source code that i use to test the calibration is below.

```
    bm->setPreFilterType(StereoBM::PREFILTER_XSOBEL);
    bm->setPreFilterSize(preFilterSize);                                        //31
    bm->setPreFilterCap(preFilterCap);                                      //31
    bm->setBlockSize(blockSize);                                            //31
    bm->setMinDisparity(minDisp);                                           //-5
    bm->setNumDisparities(numDisp);                                         //16
    bm->setTextureThreshold(textThres);                                 //10
    bm->setUniquenessRatio(uniqueRatio);                                        //15
    bm->setSpeckleWindowSize(speckleSize);                                  //101
    bm->setSpeckleRange(speckleRange);                                      //32
    bm->setDisp12MaxDiff(dispDiff);                                 //1
    cvtColor(img1,img1gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(img2,img2gray,CV_BGR2GRAY); 
    bm->compute(img1gray, img2gray, disp);
    disp.convertTo(disp8, CV_8UC1, 255/(numDisp*16.));
    displayImages();
```

All the parameters are adjustable realtime with sliders and the value commented after each row is the default or initial value.

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Please provide some codes.

Comment: if possible, provide code and sample images

Comment: I edited the question with the information requested, thanks

Comment: You should take the time to add the images and relevant code (BM parameters) to the question. Nobody wants to download and read the whole source file.

Comment: @jodis sorry, i will edit my question. I can tell you that i'm using the sample code from opencv and modified in the manner that gets in input not a list of images but take the images in real time.

Comment: code looks all right. may be just the low texture. SGBM is better for that.

Comment: @jodis yeah i know, but i need bm because is faster, i also tried sgbm3way but i have nearly the same results. I cannot see myself over 2 meters

Comment: The solution was a better calibration.